# How can i edit this line to open this url in newtab HTML

Tags: html, tabs

I don't know proper HTML coding can anyone edit this line to open the url in new tab

thanks in advance

`<meta content='5; URL=http://www.hitcpm.com/watch?key=62041d2f0b7ef3827ecd53d9cc239bce' http-equiv='refresh'/>`

Comment: That's not what meta refresh is built for. Try to look up something like opening new tabs with Javascript

Comment: this is for a blog so i cant change the whole blog coding

Comment: it should be opened whitout clicking on it

Comment: "I don't know proper HTML" so research a little bit, SO is not a free coding service...

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=javascript:window.open('http://www.hitcpm.com/watch?key=62041d2f0b7ef3827ecd53d9cc239bce','_blank');">
```

Comment: i want it to automatically open

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.hitcpm.com/watch?key=62041d2f0b7ef3827ecd53d9cc239bce">TextHere</a>
```

If you are certain you can't move to using the hyperlink tag then @Dhiraj's answer seems more your required answer

Comment: i want it to automatically open

Comment: use Javascript document load method and open link by javascript